# Featured image option is not displaying in wordpress admin area

Tags: wordpress, image, post

### Featured image option is not displaying in wordpress admin area

I am very new in wordpress. I have a wordpress site and now i need to add a featured image in my post. But i am  not getting this option in back end. I don't know what is wrong. somebody please help me.Thanks

Comment: Please change your theme and check again.

Comment: Yes.You are right. Is it some caching issue? After switching back to my original theme, i am getting this option perefectly. Thank you Anna.

Comment: Maybe a bad coded theme, @user3595293. Enable `WP_DEBUG` in wp-config to check if the theme is not dumping lots of PHP notices (a sign of bad coded theme/plugin).

Answer (score 35):

Add this code to the functions.php file of your theme:

```
// This theme uses post thumbnails
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Comment: i add this like on my function.php file but this doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 6):

If you getting this type of issue again please goto **wp-admin->add new post-> screen options**.
At the top of your page you see this **screen option** open it and check the value featured image if not checked. Now you see the option of featured image in your post page admin side.

Comment: worked for me i hope all people get it right with your answer

Answer (score 3):

Try This code inside functions.php file. This code will allow you to enable the featured image functionality inside pages. You can also pass custom post type name like ('page','post','custom_post_type_slug'). Hope this will help.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails',array('page'));
```

By adding this code to the functions.php file of your WordPress theme, you will be able to set a featured image for pages in the WordPress admin. This image can then be displayed on your site using the the_post_thumbnail function or one of its variants.

Comment: when providing answers, provide more than just code, such as explanation of why and how this will resolve the problem.